# ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7

I'm running Mariadb 10.1.22 on Centos 7 and I am getting this error message when I'm trying to start the mysql service. I haven't changed the configuration file at all and I have pasted below what the file says about where my pid file is located

pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

On my server it doesn't have a run folder under the var folder but run is located on the base directory so I created a directory called mariadb in the run directory and added a file called mariadb.pid and used the chown command to assign it to the mysql group and then restarted and that did nothing. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Also running the rpm -qa mariadb* command sho

Comment: What does the mysql/mariadb logs says? Have you looked at it?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Nothing shows up in the mariadb logs about the pid

Comment: And no errors at all?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a configuration file from MySQL, where this variable is written with the dash "pid-file", but for MariaDB according to documentation [1], you have to use an underscore "pid-file". It is not necessary to create  new MariaDB directory in var/run, just use this parameter in your mariadb.cnf:

`pid_file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

[1] https://mariadb.com/docs/ent/ref/mdb/system-variables/pid_file/